# Python Linked List removal element

Tags: python, linked-list

My code is like:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution:
    # @param {ListNode} head
    # @param {integer} val
    # @return {ListNode}
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        def printLinked(head):
            while head:
                print head.val,"->"
                head = head.next

        dummy = ListNode(0)
        dummy.next = head
        cur = dummy
        while cur and cur.next:
            if cur.next.val == val:
                cur.next = cur.next.next
            else:
                cur = cur.next
        printLinked(dummy.next)
        print "._."
        printLinked(head)
        return head
```

I find the if I return dummy.next rather than head, my code will be correct. 
But, I cannot understand what's the difference between head and dummy.next.

When my test case is head = ListNode(1),val = 1. The head will still be 1, but the dummy.next is [].

I am quite confused, because when the test case is head = 1 --> 2 --> 6 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6, val = 6, both head and dummy.next is 1-->2-->3-->4-->5. And I think there must be some misunderstand of head and dummy for me. Can any one explain it for me?

Comment: Within the `removeElements` function, you are not modifying the variable `head` (not to be confused with your `head` variable within `printLinked`) so it will still be equal `1` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Kendas But why the input as head = 1 --> 2 --> 6 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6, val = 6, both head will print as 1-->2-->3-->4-->5.

Comment: To elaborate - the `dummy.next` attribute gets modified because for the first iteration of your `while` loop `cur` _is_ `dummy` (because of `cur = dummy`).

Comment: @Kendas I am confused because dummy is modified because cur is modified? So head should be modified because dummy is modified?

Comment: @HanslenChen Basically, your code fails for the corner case because of the way you check for the corner case.

Comment: `dummy` is modified, true, however `head` is not. The `cur.next` attribute points to the same object `head` points to. When you give `cur.next` another value (`cur.next == cur.next.next`), it doesn't point to that object anymore. However, the variable `head` still points to the same object it did before.

Comment: @Kendas Thank you, it makes senses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Kendas's comment, "The cur.next attribute points to the same object head points to. When you give cur.next another value (cur.next == cur.next.next), it doesn't point to that object anymore. However, the variable head still points to the same object it did before."
Hope this helps.